# Replacing an image onclick

Tags: jquery

I am having issues with my code, I am trying to replace an image/div with another image/div on a click (with a slow fade). Then when the second image is clicked it returns to the original state.

I have managed to get so far but I am having two issues.

1 - can't seem to hide the second and forth images on page load so it only appears once the click is applied.

2 - I want to be able to do this multiple times on the same page but with the code I have so far it only works on one off the images/div.

Help please.

html

```
<div><!-- Page wrapper-->    

    <div id= "first">
        <a href="#" id="next">
            <img src="images/yb2.svg" style="height: 160px; width: 160px;">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        <a href="#" id="back">
            img src="images/ss-1a.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id= "third">
        <a href="#" id="next1">
            <img src="images/yb2.svg" style="height: 160px; width: 160px;">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="forth">
        <a href="#" id="back2">
            <img src="images/ss-1a.jpg">
    </div>

</div><!-- end of page wrapper-->
```

Jquery

```
$('#next').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#first').fadeOut('slow', function(){
         $('#second').fadeIn('slow');
     });
});
$('#back').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#second').fadeOut('slow', function(){
         $('#first').fadeIn('slow');
     });
});
$('#next1').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#third').fadeOut('slow', function(){
         $('#second').fadeIn('slow');
     });
});
$('#back2').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#forth').fadeOut('slow', function(){
          $('#first').fadeIn('slow');
     });
});
```

Comment: You want it to work like this? http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/nhq9d5qa/

Comment: the closing `a` is missing on `second` and `fourth`... ;)

Comment: @webeno Good spot :) , just added this in the fiddle but it also worked before without the closing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/nhq9d5qa/) with the following adjustments: for 1) - to hide the divs with the ids #second and #forth I just added as css

```
#second, #forth {
    display:none;
}
```

And to work like I think it's intended for 2)  I've adjusted the code as follows:

```
$('#next').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#first').fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $('#second').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
$('#back').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#second').fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $('#first').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
$('#next1').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#third').fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $('#forth').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
$('#back2').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#forth').fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $('#third').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thats awesome, seems so simple now it's done, Thank you on to my next battle